# how to get the node "[StepHeader] in my example" as a object to add new child nodes dynamically in vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript

```
<Report TcName=" Testing" >
  <TestSuite Desc="ADI [UK]">
    <TestCase TcName=" Testing" >
      <Step ID="Step 1" Desc=" ">
        <StepDetails Status="4"  StepType="Step">Step 1 Info </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails Status="3"  StepType="Step">Step 1 Warning </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails Status="1" StepType="Step">Step 1 passed </StepDetails>
        <StepHeader StepType="STEPHEADER" Status="2">
          <StepDetails StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 Info </StepDetails>
          <StepDetails Status="3" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 Warning </StepDetails>
          <StepDetails Status="1" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 passed </StepDetails>
          <StepDetails Status="2"  StepType="STEPHEADER" ScreenShotPath="D:\Git\automation\Projects\SOA\ADI\Reports\_Screenshots\ADI_UK_SOA-API_QAT2_201442110481\ADI SOA-API 4_21_2014 10_48_09 AM.png">Step Header 1 failed </StepDetails>
          <StepDetails Status="4"  StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 1 DONE </StepDetails>
          <StepHeader>
            <StepDetails Status="4"StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Info </StepDetails>
            <StepDetails Status="3"StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Warning </StepDetails>
            <StepDetails Status="1" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 passed </StepDetails>
          </StepHeader>
        </StepHeader>
      </Step>
    </TestCase>
  </TestSuite>
</Report>
```

how to get the node "[StepHeader] in my example" as a object to add new child nodes dynamically in vbscript and i am using QTP to create the XML file.

Comment: There are *two* stepheaders in your example. You must say how to identify the desired one.

Comment: sorry , the last stepheader .

Answer (score 0):

Use .selectSingleNode with a suitable XPATH query to select the node, use .createElement to create a new StepDetails element, use .appendChild to append the element ot the found node:

```
  Dim oFS      : Set oFS      = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Dim sFSpec   : sFSpec       = goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\testdata\xml\23193903.xml")
  Dim objMSXML : Set objMSXML = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
  objMSXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
  objMSXML.async = False
  objMSXML.load sFSpec

  If 0 = objMSXML.parseError Then
     Dim sXPath : sXPath    = "/Report/TestSuite/TestCase/Step/StepHeader/StepHeader"
     Dim ndFnd  : Set ndFnd = objMSXML.selectSingleNode(sXPath)
     If ndFnd Is Nothing Then
        WScript.Echo sXPath, "not found"
     Else
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.xml
        ndFnd.AppendChild objMSXML.createElement("StepDetails")
        WScript.Echo ndFnd.xml
     End If
  Else
     WScript.Echo objMSXML.parseError.reason
  End If
```

output:

```
<StepHeader>
        <StepDetails Status="4" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Info </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails Status="3" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Warning </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails Status="1" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 passed </StepDetails>
</StepHeader>
<StepHeader>
        <StepDetails Status="4" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Info </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails Status="3" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 Warning </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails Status="1" StepType="STEPHEADER">Step Header 2 passed </StepDetails>
        <StepDetails/></StepHeader>
```

Use the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to look up the functions used.

Comment: ok , but what i want is to create a function every time i call it  , it add a new child "stepheader" to the last child and i mean if i have 20 "stepheader"s to the "Step" node it adds a new "stepheader" node and every childelement parsed with the previous node .